# Swagger-ui shows null for List<MonetartyAmount>

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I am using swagger on my springboot project.
The problem appears for endpoint which returns the entity with list of MonetaryAmount i.e. (`List<MonetaryAmount> rates`)

Swagger-ui shows incorrect data for such endpoints as:

```
{
  "rates": [
    null
  ]
}
```

However I expect to see each MonetaryAmount value as pair of Double and String. Smth like this:

```
{
  "rates": [
   {"currency":"EUR", "rate": 12.23}
  ]
}
```

I tried to use directModelSubstitute but it seems it is not working for List.

Here is my model :

```
public class CurrencyRatesResponse implements Serializable {

private List<MonetaryAmount> rates;

public CurrencyRatesResponse() {
}

public CurrencyRatesResponse(List<MonetaryAmount> rates) {
    this.rates = rates;
}

public List<MonetaryAmount> getRates() {
    return rates;
}

public void setRates(List<MonetaryAmount> rates) {
    this.rates = rates;
}
}
```

And here is an example of my endpoint

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/public/rates", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public CurrencyRatesResponse getRates() {...}
```

Generated swagger JSON:

```
 "/public/rates":{
         "get":{
            "tags":[
               "rate-endpoint"
            ],
            "summary":"getRates",
            "operationId":"getRatesUsingGET",
            "produces":[
               "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
            ],
            "parameters":[
               {
                 ....
               }
            ],
            "responses":{
               "200":{
                  "description":"OK",
                  "schema":{
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/CurrencyRatesResponse"
                  }
               },
               "401":{
                  "description":"Unauthorized"
               },
               "403":{
                  "description":"Forbidden"
               },
               "404":{
                  "description":"Not Found"
               }
            }
         }
      }
    }  ....

   "CurrencyRatesResponse":{
         "type":"object",
         "properties":{
            "rates":{
               "type":"array",
               "items":{
                  "$ref":"#/definitions/MonetaryAmount"
               }
            }
         },
         "title":"CurrencyRatesResponse"
      },
```

Comment: Which SpringFox version and [Swagger UI version](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/version-detection.md) are you using? Can you also post the `MonetaryAmount` class? Do `CurrencyRatesResponse` and `MonetaryAmount` have any annotations? Can you also post your generated Swagger JSON/YAML file? (I'm trying to understand if the issue is with annotations or with Swagger UI.)

Comment: I`m using Money as standard implementation of https://javamoney.github.io/apidocs/javax/money/MonetaryAmount.html

Comment: swagger json attached to original question

Comment: Thanks. Does the Swagger JSON file include the `MonetaryAmount` definition?

Comment: no. And that is the root of problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several steps to achieve this.

First of all, we need proper objectMapper so`MonetaryAmount` gets mapped to proper object with two fields `currency` and `rate`. To achieve this we need to add custom module for the springfox's objectMapper.

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.zalando.jackson.datatype.money.MoneyModule;
import springfox.documentation.schema.configuration.ObjectMapperConfigured;

@Component
public class SwaggerJacksonModule implements ApplicationListener<ObjectMapperConfigured> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ObjectMapperConfigured event) {
        event.getObjectMapper().registerModule(new MoneyModule());
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**  We add a listener to the springfox's `ObjectMapperConfigured` event and whenever the event is triggered we simply get the mapper and register our module. I use [Zalando's](https://github.com/zalando/jackson-datatype-money) Jackson Datatype Money library so that I don't write my own.

Next step would be to work on actual Swagger representation. Let's create our own representation object `MonetaryWrapper` which we gonna use it to substitute `MonetaryAmount`.

```
public class MonetaryWrapper {

    private BigDecimal amount;

    private String currency;

  // getters and setters  (getters are important)
}
```

In order to get Single object representations right it's enough to add `.directModelSubstitute(MonetaryAmount.class, MonetaryWrapper.class)` to the `Docket` object.

**BUT** It's not that simple for collections. e.g List in this case. We need add Special `AlternateTypeRule` object into `Docket` object in order for lists show properly.

More details on this topic in springfox's [documentation](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#answers-to-common-questions-and-problems)

*Something like this:*

```
TypeResolver resolver = new TypeResolver();
AlternateTypeRule monetaryAmountListRule =
        newRule(resolver.resolve(List.class,  MonetaryAmount.class),
                resolver.resolve(List.class, MonetaryWrapper.class))
```

And finally our `Docket` bean would look something like this:

```
@Bean
public Docket productApi() {
    TypeResolver resolver = new TypeResolver();
    AlternateTypeRule monetaryAmountListRule =
            newRule(resolver.resolve(List.class,  MonetaryAmount.class),
                    resolver.resolve(List.class, MonetaryWrapper.class));


    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .alternateTypeRules(monetaryAmountListRule)
            .directModelSubstitute(MonetaryAmount.class, MonetaryWrapper.class)
            .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.swagger.test"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/public.*")).build();
}
```

*And some demo screenshots here:*

Demo when **executing** request:

[image: DEMO endpoint result]

Demo just for **object description**:

[image: Demo representation result]

Comment: for those wondering where does newRule comes from, it is AlternateTypeRules.newRule. Alternatively, you can import import springfox.documentation.schema.AlternateTypeRules.newRule; and just newRule in your code.